# How to create a table from CodeBehind using ASP.NET Table Control methods (using, Table,TableRow,TableColumn,TableHeader etc.)

Tags: asp.net

I need to create a table, which will have one header and [Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8CXw.png) multiple checkboxes. Can someone please give some reference so that I can understand how ASP.NET table control works. I already went thorough MSDN blog. So but I was unable understand that. I will be very happy if someone can explain in details.

Comment: Why you don't us e a `GridView`? It will be easier because you don't run into page-lifecycle or viewstate issues.

Comment: Even I thought of using it. But we are not allowed to use it.

Comment: Or better yet, an `asp:Repeater`

Comment: Yeah I was grazing on the same as well... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see your image because work blocks imgur.com, so hopefully this helps.  We use something like this to create custom ListView Controls.  But since you can't use a GridView, I would suggest putting a PlaceHolder control on the page.  Once the table is created then add it to the PlaceHolder.

```
    Table t = new Table();
    TableHeaderRow th = new TableHeaderRow();
    //add the header row to table t
    t.Rows.Add(th);
    //add three columns to the header row with a label for text
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        TableCell td = new TableCell();
        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.Text = "Header Label: " + i.ToString();
        td.Controls.Add(lb);
        th.Cells.Add(td);
    }
    //add the rows, say you need five
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        //add three columns to the table row with a checkbox
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            //add the cells with a checkbox
            TableCell td1 = new TableCell();
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.Text = "CheckBox: " + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();
            td.Controls.Add(cb);
            tr.Cells.Add(td1);
        }
        t.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
    placeHolder.Controls.Add(t);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. It really helped me a lot. Appreciate it.

Comment: What was mentioned as Control.Add, it should be Controls.Add. Thanks a ton by the way. Just wanted to make your answer look perfect, thus updated this small error. ;-)